# What would be the contents of canonical Huffman encoded bit stream?

Tags: algorithm, compression, gzip, huffman-code, encoder

Let's consider the following example with symbol- code length - canonical code data.

```
A - 2 - 00
B - 2 - 01
D - 2 - 10
C - 3 - 110 
E - 3 - 111
```

I was wondering what would be the contents of encoded bit stream? Is it 00 01 10 110 111 (basically all codes) or 2,2,2,3,3 in binary equivalent as corresponding code lengths? I wanted to add here that some resources say just transmit code as encoded bit stream and few other resources talk about throwing code away from encoded bit stream and transmit only code length data.

Answer (score 2):

### Encoded bitstream

The code is:

```
00 01 10 110 111
```

Note that if we sent the code of 2,2,2,3,3, then it would be impossible to decide if the input was AAACC or BBBEE (or many other equivalent choices).

Because Huffman codes are a [prefix code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code) it means that we can unambiguously decode the bitstream despite not knowing where the spaces are.

In other words, when given the output 000110110111, we can uniquely decode it as ABDCE.

### Transmitting code table

I think the confusion may be because you need to possess two things to decode the bitstream:

1. The coded bitstream
2. The lookup table

These two things are often coded in very different ways.

In many cases the lookup table is fixed in advance so does not need to be transmitted.

However, if the probabilities can change, then we need to tell the recipient what code table to use.  In this case we can just transmit the lengths of each code word and this gives enough information for the receiver to construct the canonical Huffman code.  Alternatives are also possible, for example we can send the number of each code word length followed by the values.  This alternative is used by JPEG and explained more below.

### Example

The JPEG image codec uses Huffman tables.  Normally some default tables are used, but it is possible to optimize the size of images by transmitting a custom Huffman code.  A tutorial about this is [here](http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/optimized-jpeg.html).

Another description of the way of transmitting the Huffman table is [here](http://imrannazar.com/Let's-Build-a-JPEG-Decoder%3A-Huffman-Tables).  The code lengths are sent (as bytes) followed by the code values (again as bytes).

Code to read it (taken from the link) is:

```
// Next sixteen bytes are the counts for each code length
u8 counts[16];
for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    counts[i] = fgetc(fp);
    ctr++;
}

// Remaining bytes are the data values to be mapped
// Build the Huffman map of (length, code) -> value
for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < counts[i]; j++) {
        huffData[table][huffKey(i + 1, code)] = fgetc(fp);
        code++;
        ctr++;
    }
    code <<= 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, as some resources say the greatest advantage we get in case of canonical Huffman from regular Huffman is by not sending code as encoded bitstream. By that, we make the size of bit stream smaller. As you are saying about look up table, can you please tell me the structure of that look up table, which needs to be sent? Is it in form of symbol-codelength-code ?

Comment: @beginner I've added more explanation about how the lookup table can be sent

Comment: Interestingly that scheme cannot encode the simple flat code of 256 8-bit codes, since the maximum count for a code length is 255.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is how to send a description of the code to the receiver, so that the receiver knows how to decode the following code values.

There are many ways of varying levels of sophistication, depending on how much effort you want to put into compressing the description of the code. Peter de Rivaz describes a simple approach used by JPEG, which is to send 16 counts of the number of codes of each length, followed by the byte values of each of those symbols. So for your code that would be (in hex):

`00 03 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 41 42 43 44 45`

That's not terribly compact, and it can't represent one of the possible codes, which is 256 8-bit codes, since you are limited to a count of 255 for each length.

The first thing you can do is cut off the code lengths when you have a complete code. It is easy to calculate how many code patterns are left, in which case you can simply end it when there are none left. Follow that with the symbols. You then have:

`00 03 02 41 42 43 44 45`

We don't need eight bits for each count, since they are limited by the constraints on those counts. For example, you can't have more than two one-bit codes. So we could code these in fewer bits, e.g. n+1 bits for n codes. So two bits, three, bits, and so on until the code is complete. For your code, now in binary:

`00 011 0010`

followed by the bytes `41 42 43 44 45`, offset in the bit stream appropriately. Now the list of counts takes nine bits instead of 24. Since we know that there can only be 256 symbols, we can cap off the number of bits for each count at nine, allowing for the count 256, solving the previous problem of not being able to represent the flat code. Then if the code is limited to 16 bits in length (as it is for JPEG), the largest number of bytes needed for the counts is 14.5, less than the original 16. Often the counts will end before 14.5 bytes.

You can get even more sophisticated, noting that at each code length, you have a limit on the possible count of codes of that length due to the shorter code lengths using up patterns. Then the number of bits for each count can be variable, based on how many possible values there are. Then the counts description would be:

`00 011 10`, then the eight-bit values `41 42 43 44 45`

Since we have no preceding patterns used up for lengths one and two, those still need to be two and three bits respectively. However we now have only three possibilities left for length three: the counts 0, 1, or 2. A count of 3 would oversubscribe the code. So we can use two bits for that last one. It is now seven bits instead of nine, and this greatly reduces the number of bits in the counts for codes that use longer code lengths.

An entirely different scheme is the one used by the deflate format (used in zip, gzip, zlib, png, etc.). There the number of code lengths to follow is sent first, followed by the code length of each symbol in order up to the last one. The symbols themselves are implied by the code length location. That results in lots of zeros, to represent symbols that are not present. So for your code there would be a 70 to go up to symbol 69 ("E"), followed by 65 zeros, then 2 2 2 3 3. That seems awfully long, and it is. deflate then run-length and Huffman codes that list of lengths, to compress it. The long strings of zeros get compressed to a few bits, and the short lengths are also just a few bits each. So then you have to first send a description of the code lengths code lengths code (!) so that you can decode that.

You can read the [deflate specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951) for more information on that scheme. [brotli](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7932) uses a similar scheme, with more sophistication still.